# Custom font is only applied on first textview and button

Tags: android, customization, findviewbyid

Custom font is only applied on the first textView and Button, not on the rest.I had used findViewByid to get the Views. I had used fontFam id for textview and btFontFam for button

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="@string/L1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/LBtn"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/L2"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/L3"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/L4"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/SBtn"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fontFam);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btfontFam);
    bt.setTypeface(tf);

}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you show Where have you defined the ID's in your xml file ? I can just see many TextView's and Button's with no ID's. Also, you would need to set the TypeFace for each of the TextView's or buttons inside your onCreate using each of their ID's. So define ID's for each TextView and Button and set their TypeFace in the same way you've done for those two.

Comment: Yeah, so 1. it doesn't look like you defined IDs. 2. It doesn't look like you're setting the typeface for anything other than one `Button` and one `TextView`, so I really don't know why you're expecting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should extends the TextView, Button,... class to using custom fonts.

First, add new property to "values/attrs.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Second, rewrite the TextView class:

```
package com.ex.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, using with custom font:

```
<com.ex.ui.TextViewPlus
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ex"  
android:id="@android:id/text1"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:customFont="Roboto-Light.ttf"/>
```

Note:

"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ex" => "com.ex" is the main package, that mean you can access the resource via com.ex.R